# disable/hide settings depending on a switch on ios

Tags: ios, settings

I've made a settings screen using the Settings.bundle/Root.plist
Recently my client has seen some apps disable options based on a switch. And now they want something like that.

After searching here and apple resources a lot of people say it's not possible, but I see some apps do this. My question is how can i disable or hide an item or group based on other option.

The apps that do what i'm talking about are using the iphone's definition app, so it's not a costume settings screens in app.

Sorry for the bad english. Thank you for any assistance on this matter.

Comment: What is "iphone's definition app" ?

Comment: i ment the iphones's settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just going to repeat what the others said and say that it is not possible. It is a static list, always. If you think you've seen an app that does do it, please indicate which one that is and what setting this pertains to. I'd be interested to take a look at that.

Comment: last app that they showed me that does this was called "Nike + iPod"

Comment: That is an app that comes with iOS. Obviously, Apple can make exceptions to its own rules.

Comment: Actually i didn't know that. Thank you alot for your time :) Now i just need to explain this to the client (haha).